# Upload photos to WordPress via ftp w/ [gallery] shortcode?

Tags: gallery

Is there a way to upload photos to WordPress via FTP instead of uploading them one by one through the dashboard?

Also, does WordPress' built in gallery allow commenting on each individual photo? If not, are there any simple gallery plugins out there that has this feature built-in?

Comment: If you add the media through the media library you can upload several at once, it's not limited to one, you can then attach or insert those items into posts at a later date. Attachments also have their own page(usually a sub-url of the post/page they're attached to).

Answer (score 1):

Another option (one that I'm using to convert from NextGen Gallery to native WordPress galleries), is to use the [Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/) Plugin, to import images to the WordPress Media Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Nextgen-gallery has all those features you needed, but not a simple plugin.